# firebase-functions - best way to start processing data / RESTful API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project that currently is using firebase-functions as its backend and most of the time firebase-functions are used to do some light weight modification in the database.
However, we have some functions that are listening for changes in `request/[userId]/startProcessingSomething` documents. Those documents are being used to start some heavier data processing and saving the outcome to specific documents in firebase db. And it worked in the beginning, but after a while we experienced race conditions and we wanted to know when the processing of above requests is finished, so there was an idea to use `metadata/[userId]/processingSomethingMetadata` where we kept the information about the current status of the data processing.

I did not like creating artificial documents for metadata so I am pushing to use endpoints (standard GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) to handle some operations. However, I hear opinions that this is not the firebase-functions way.

Do you have any idea, hints how to handle more complex processing / requests?

Is using RESTful api with firebase-functions a bad idea?

Comment: By race conditions you mean while accessing firestore correct? If so, have you used transactions to prevent that? Also, where is this heavy processing happening? On the cloud functions themselves?